# Shorten the Code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to shorten my jQuery code. Do you see any possibility?

After that I want to get a function which makes my content fly in form the side of my page. Can you help me with that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#portfolio").click(function() {
    $("#stage").load("pages/portfolio.html");
  });
  $("#biografie").click(function() {
    $("#stage").load("pages/biografie.html");
  });
  $("#kontakt").click(function() {
    $("#stage").load("pages/kontakt.html");
  });
  $("#leistungen").click(function() {
    $("#stage").load("pages/leistungen.html");
  });
  $("#impressum").click(function() {
    $("#stage").load("pages/impressum.html");
  });
  $("#datenschutz").click(function() {
    $("#stage").load("pages/datenschutz.html");
  });
});
```

```html
<nav id="navibar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#portfolio" id="portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#biografie" id="biografie">Biografie</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#kontakt" id="kontakt">Kontakt</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#leistungen" id="leistungen">Leistungen</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: If your code works and you think it needs  review/refactoring suggestion, please, next time post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 5):

`this` value of the event handler refers to the clicked element. You could simply use the `id` attribute of clicked element by using `this.id`:

```
$('#navibar a').on('click', function() {
   $("#stage").load("pages/" + this.id + ".html");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, change your selector like

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $("[data-url]")
        .click(function() {
            $("#stage").load($(this).attr('data-url'));
         });
});
```

then add custom attributes to your anchor elements like

```
    <li><a href="#portfolio" id="portfolio" data-load="pages/portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#biografie" id="biografie"  data-load=" data-load="pages/portfolio.html"">Biografie</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#kontakt" id="kontakt"  data-load="pages/kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#leistungen" id="leistungen"  data-load="pages/leistungen.html">Leistungen</a>
    </li>
```

If the path will always be based on the id, you can simply do

```
$(document).ready(
      function() {
        $("#navbar a")
            .click(function() {
                $("#stage").load('pages/' + $(this).attr('id') + '.html');
             });
    });
```

Comment: holy cow, you have almost the exact thing I was going to answer with.  Though instead of .attr('data-url') I'd just do .data('url')

Comment: Not really a good way of doing it, because if you have to add another link, it means that you will need to add the id in the $ selector as well

Comment: Also if the elements shared a common class, (ex. loadable), you could use that as your delegated selector

Comment: @Taplar Since they're already using a custom attribute, just use that - `$("[data-load]")`

Comment: True, though if done that way i'd still use a delegated binder off of the navibar to have only one event handler.

Comment: @Taplar Agreed. There are definitely improvements, I was just addressing the selector part

Answer (score 1):

I will do like this:

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fly").click(function() {
    $("#stage").load("pages/"+$(this).attr("id")+".html");
  });
});
```

HMTL

```
<nav id="navibar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#portfolio" id="portfolio" class="fly">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#biografie" id="biografie" class="fly">Biografie</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#kontakt" id="kontakt" class="fly">Kontakt</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#leistungen" id="leistungen" class="fly">Leistungen</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<nav id="navibar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#portfolio" id="portfolio" class="loadable" data-load="pages/portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#biografie" id="biografie" class="loadable" data-load="pages/biografie.html">Biografie</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#kontakt" id="kontakt" class="loadable" data-load="pages/kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#leistungen" id="leistungen" class="loadable" data-load="pages/leistungen.html">Leistungen</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $stage = $("#stage");

    $('#navibar').on('click', '.loadable', function(){
        $stage.load( $(this).data('load') );
    });
});
```

Similar to an answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<nav id="navibar">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#portfolio" id="portfolio" class="link">Portfolio</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#biografie" id="biografie" class="link">Biografie</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#kontakt" id="kontakt" class="link">Kontakt</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#leistungen" id="leistungen" class="link">Leistungen</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $(".link").click(function(e){
    event.preventDefault();
    var page = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#stage").load("pages/"+page+".html");
  });
});
```

#### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h7yvgk3j/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change both HTML and Javascript code.

```html
    <nav id="navibar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#portfolio" id="portfolio" class="nav-item" nav-url="pages/portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#biografie" id="biografie" class="nav-item" nav-url="pages/biografie.html">Biografie</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#kontakt" id="kontakt" class="nav-item" nav-url="pages/kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#leistungen" id="leistungen" class="nav-item" nav-url="pages/leistungen.html">Leistungen</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-item").click(function() {
     var myUrl = this.getAttribute('nav-url');
      $(".stage").html(myUrl);
     // load corresponding url
     //$("#stage").load(myUrl);
  });
   
});
```

[working code in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammed2raja/q3fvvkh7/)